# NSMutableArray when using arrayWithArray the mutable array becomes the right size, but the object are all out of scope

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
NSArray * ComicArray = [TCSDataBase fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:@"ComicDB" withPredicate:nil];
    [ComicArray retain];

    arrayOfComics = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:ComicArray];
    [[arrayOfComics valueForKey:@"Name"] sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    [ComicArray release];
```

Why are all the object in the arrayOfComics out of scope?

EDIT: I tried doing this:

```
NSArray * ComicArray = [TCSDataBase fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:@"ComicDB" withPredicate:predicate];
    arrayOfComics =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [ComicArray count]; i++) {
        [arrayOfComics addObject:[ComicArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    [[arrayOfComics valueForKey:@"Name"] sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

All the objects in `arrayOfComics` are still out of scope....

EDIT: This works, the objects in arrayOfComicsTest are NOT "out of scope". I am not sure why this works yet when i do arrayOfComics they are out of scope. `arrayOfComics` is a class variable `NSMutableArray * arrayOfComics` in the .h. It is not used anywhere until this point.

```
NSMutableArray * arrayOfComicsTest = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:ComicArray];
```

Comment: Why are you retaining, and then releasing, `ComicArray`?

Comment: Also, why are you creating an NSMutableArray copy of the array, then creating 2 subsequent NSArrays from that NSMutableArray?

Comment: @BoltClock - The objects within the NSMutableArray are all out of scope, they are objects of a Custom Class that i made.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard - fetchManagedObjectsForEntity returns a non-retained NSArray so i need to retain it so i don't loose it. Once i am done with it i release it.

Comment: @Mausimo No you don't. You should read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). In short, you only need to retain it if you're going to hold on to it past the current method.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard - Thanks for the info, i think i am confusing myself because i am changing this code. Previously i had ComicArray as a class variable and was holding onto it past the current method. That being said, i did not know "that you have to retain only if you are going to be using it past the current method". Also i have updated the code i had the wrong method i meant to use sortUsingSelector.

Comment: When i look at the ComicArray it shows 69 items and when you look at the items they are addresses in memory - fair enough as they are objects of class "Comic" that contain various variables including "Name". After i do the arrayOfComics = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:ComicArray]; when i look at arrayOfComics it has 69 itmes except when you look at the items they are all "out of scope" and whenever you access these items it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time I was having a bunch of problems because I did not fully understand the difference between mutable and non mutable arrays, as well as the various return values from array operations.

I eventually fixed this by making a bunch of changes.

Thanks to everyone that provided help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....still i m not getting why u r not using `executeFetchRequest`

```
NSArray * ComicArray = [TCSDataBase fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:@"ComicDB" withPredicate:nil];
    [ComicArray retain];

    arrayOfComics = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:ComicArray];
    [[arrayOfComics valueForKey:@"Name"] sortedUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: fetchManagedObjectsForEntity returns an NSArray, that is why i am using ComicArray as a NSArray

Comment: This answer is wrong at many levels. Simply changing from NSArray to NSMutableArray doesn't make it so. Also, the return value of sortedArrayUsingSelector is still being ignored.

Comment: @Johan Kool sorry for doing that blunder mistake ....but still trying to collect the sollution

Comment: fetchManagedObjectsForEntity: is just a wrapper for my coredata calls, this function actually uses executeFetchRequest:

Comment: my problem is that arrayOfComics is getting 69 blank objects when i do [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:ComicArray]; . For you info - ComicArray is loading the 69 correct objects and i can see them when i debug, when i look at the arrayOfComics they are "out of scope"

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *comicArray = [TCSDataBase fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:@"ComicDB" withPredicate:nil];
NSArray *sortedComicNamesArray = [[comicArray valueForKey:@"Name"] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Note that the latter array only has the names of the comics sorted. It does not contain a sorted list of your comics.

BTW, if you want a sorted list for your comics (not just the names) simply create the proper predicate to use in the `-fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:withPredicate:` method.

Comment: You can sort with a predicate?

Comment: Ah sorry, no you can't. I was confused with `NSFetchRequest`. The method you'll have to use is than `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `-executeFetchRequest:error:`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to retain your array "arrayOfComics". Put a break point in your code and immediately when it is created, all the objects will be available. But if you want to use that array in some other method, all the objects go out of scope as you are not retaining.
Else it will have the scope upto the method in which it is assigned.

After correction, your code must look like:

```
NSArray * ComicArray = [TCSDataBase fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:@"ComicDB" withPredicate:nil];
[ComicArray retain];

arrayOfComics = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:ComicArray];
[arrayOfComics retain];
[[arrayOfComics valueForKey:@"Name"] sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

[ComicArray release];
```

Please note that if you want to reassign arrayOfComics, you have to release and then assign.

Comment: Hey, debugging the arrayOfComics objects are out of scope immediately, the retain does not help.

Comment: Does ComicArray have the objects? From my code, try removing [ComicArray retain]; and [ComicArray release];

Comment: ComicArray does indeed have the objects. I have checked many times in the debugger. Removing the retain release did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the objects are "out of scope" I presume you mean you can't see them in the debugger.  If this is the case, stop worrying about it as it happens quite a lot, it's just an implementation feature.  In particular, core data doesn't always fetch an actual object till it's needed (read about [faulting](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003397-SW8) in the Core Data Programming Guide).  If you right click on the array in the debugger display and select "print description to console", it'll print the array and all its objects quite happily.

Your code does have a problem though.  This line:

[[arrayOfComics valueForKey:@"Name"] sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

is nonsense.  First it gets an array of the name keys of your objects and then it tries to sort it (which may fail unless the array of names happens to be mutable).  Then it throws away the result.

Comment: I commented out the sort using code, the arrayOfComics still breaks in other places in the code (after it has been loaded). I'm sure its not loading properly... if i look at the ComicArray, it does indeed get loaded from core data. Then when i try to make an NSMutableArray from the ComicArray the NSMutableArray does not load...

Comment: According to this, sortUsingSelector with NSMutableArray will sort the array in place. So after this, the current array should be sorted...?
Sorts the array’s elements in ascending order, as determined by the comparison method specified by a given selector.

- (void)sortUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator